# XAML/C# How to create a two-way binding with one source and multiple targets?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I want to define a time span using three text boxes; one for hours, minutes, and seconds. Data validation is out of scope to my question.

I define the three text boxes in xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Test_Timer.Timer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test_Timer"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="timer">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal>
        <TextBox x:Name="hoursBox" />
        <TextBlock Text=":" />
        <TextBox x:Name="minutesBox" />
        <TextBlock Text=":" />
        <TextBox x:Name="secondsBox" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

My ViewModel contains a single TimeSpan Property, and gives notifications whenever the time changes (via INotifyPropertyChanged). The ViewModel is generic and being used in other views. It would be unacceptable to add three separate properties for hours, minutes, and seconds so that I could bind to them individually.

```
class TimerVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private TimeSpan m_duration = new TimeSpan();
    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get { return m_duration; }
        set
        {
            m_duration = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Duration));
        }
    }
}
```

**How would I setup a two-way binding between the three textboxes and the Duration property?**

Comment: wpf and uwp are 2 separate platforms please put appropriate tag for only the platform your app is in.

Comment: @touseefbsb The xaml and binding components are common between uwp and wpf. As my question pertains mostly to the binding, I believe it applies to both platforms and would gladly accept an answer using either. However, your point is noted and I will change the title to remove UWP.

Comment: have you tried binding each TextBox to nested properties like 'Duration.Hours' to the hours textbox, and so on?

Comment: The Hours, Minutes, and Seconds properties on TimeSpan are read-only. I expect I'll need to do some sort of processing to combine them before-hand. Might just be one of those cases where it has to be done in the code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Define the converter as a **StaticResource** in your Grid and then Bind textboxes to duration along with a **Converter** and a **Converter Parameter**.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Test_Timer.Timer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test_Timer"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="timer">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:DateFormatter x:Key="DurationConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal>            
            <TextBox x:Name="hoursBox" Text="{Binding vm.Duration, Mode=TwoWay,
                            Converter={StaticResource DurationConverter}, 
                            ConverterParameter=hoursBox}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=":" />
            <TextBox x:Name="minutesBox" Text="{Binding vm.Duration, Mode=TwoWay,
                            Converter={StaticResource DurationConverter}, 
                            ConverterParameter=minutesBox}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=":" />
            <TextBox x:Name="secondsBox" Text="{Binding vm.Duration, Mode=TwoWay,
                            Converter={StaticResource DurationConverter}, 
                            ConverterParameter=secondsBox}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid
</UserControl>
```

then you need to define this converter in your backend within the namespace **Test_Timer** like so :

```
public class DurationFormatter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        string formatString = parameter as string;
        if (formatString == "hoursBox")
        {
            return ((TimeSpan)value).Hours.ToString();
        }
        else if (formatString == "minutesBox")
        {
            return ((TimeSpan)value).Minutes.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return ((TimeSpan)value).Seconds.ToString();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        string formatString = parameter as string;
        if (formatString == "hoursBox")
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromHours(ConvertToInt32(((string)value)));//Here you get the hours value sent from textbox to backend.
        }
        else if (formatString == "minutesBox")
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(ConvertToInt32(((string)value)));//Here you get the minutes value sent from textbox to backend.
        }
        else
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ConvertToInt32(((string)value)));//Here you get the seconds value sent from textbox to backend.
        }
    }
}
```

the convert method gets the data from your viewModel Property and converts it as you want and then returns the data towards your UI ( textbox ).

convertback method gets the data from your textbox and converts it then sends it to your viewmodel property.

I have shown you how you can achieve this. You only need to figure out how you want to deal with the convert back method, the code I have written here gets a string from the textbox and converts than strong to a **TimeSpan** object accordingly (depending upon whether it is coming from which textbox **ConverterParameter** helps us in that), and then assigns it to the viewmodel Duration property with return statement. Now it is upto you how you want to combine them before sending them to Duration.

**Suggestion**

Depending on your scenario you need to combine hours, minutes and seconds somehow and then assign it to the Duration of your viewmodel. So I am suggesting 1 possible way to do that.

make a public static class which can hold 3 static properties, and they will keep getting updated in **Convert** and **ConvertBack** methods so this will help you to combine.

```
public static class DurationValues
{
    public static string Hours="";
    public static string Minutes="";
    public static string Seconds="";
}
```

and have the convert class as following.

```
public class DurationFormatter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        string formatString = parameter as string;
        if (formatString == "hoursBox")
        {
            string rValue = ((TimeSpan)value).Hours.ToString();
            DurationValues.Hours=rValue;
            return rValue;
        }
        else if (formatString == "minutesBox")
        {
            string rValue = ((TimeSpan)value).Minutes.ToString();
            DurationValues.Minutes=rValue;
            return rValue;
        }
        else
        {
            string rValue = ((TimeSpan)value).Seconds.ToString();
            DurationValues.Seconds=rValue;
            return rValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        string formatString = parameter as string;
        if (formatString == "hoursBox")
        {
            DurationValues.Hours = (string)value;
            var ts = new TimeSpan (DurationValues.Hours,DurationValues.Minutes,DurationValues.Seconds);
            return ts;
        }
        else if (formatString == "minutesBox")
        {
            DurationValues.Minutes = (string)value;
            var ts = new TimeSpan (DurationValues.Hours,DurationValues.Minutes,DurationValues.Seconds);
            return ts;
        }
        else
        {
            DurationValues.Seconds = (string)value;
            var ts = new TimeSpan (DurationValues.Hours,DurationValues.Minutes,DurationValues.Seconds);
            return ts;
        }
    }
}
```

> Another example of IValueConverter : https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/

Comment: does this really work? can you combine the 3 properties and create a `TimeSpan` with hours, minutes and seconds set or does it create and new `TimeSpan` every time?

Comment: it creates a new TimeSpan everytime in ConvertBack method, how you combine the 3 of them actually depends on your scenario and you have to figure that out.

Comment: This is a good start. It definitely solves the problem of updating the textboxes from the Duration property. But as you mentioned, it doesn't solve how to combine the textbox properties into a duration. I'm not sure why you think this piece depends on the scenario. Can you elaborate? The problem I foresee is that we only have access to one of the Textbox values at a time in the converter, so it wouldn't be possible to combine the three.

Comment: @SimCard I have updated my answer and added a suggestion of 1 way you can achieve exactly what you need

Comment: the reason I said this depends on scenario is because you stated in your question tht you do not want to use 3 seperate properties in your viewmodel , because that actually changes the way we implement this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your solution works, so I have marked it as correct. I have a slightly more robust way to implement this so that I can have more than one timer. I'll likely update the answer once it's implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I ended up with (99% inspired by the answer by touseefbsb).

Here is the XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Test_Timer.Timer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test_Timer"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="timer">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:TimeSpanConverter x:Key="TimeSpanConverter" />
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal>            
            <TextBox x:Name="hoursBox" Text="{Binding vm.Duration, Mode=TwoWay,
                        Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}, 
                        ConverterParameter=hours}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=":" />
            <TextBox x:Name="minutesBox" Text="{Binding vm.Duration, Mode=TwoWay,
                        Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}, 
                        ConverterParameter=minutes}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=":" />
            <TextBox x:Name="secondsBox" Text="{Binding vm.Duration, Mode=TwoWay,
                        Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}, 
                        ConverterParameter=seconds}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the Converter:

```
class TimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public int Hours { get; set; }

    public int Minutes { get; set; }

    public int Seconds { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string strParam = (string)parameter;
        TimeSpan ts = (TimeSpan)value;

        switch(strParam.ToLower())
        {
            case "hours":
                return ts.Hours.ToString();
            case "minutes":
                return ts.Minutes.ToString();
            case "seconds":
                return ts.Seconds.ToString();
        }
        return "0";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string strParam = (string)parameter;
        int intVal = int.Parse((string)value);

        switch (strParam.ToLower())
        {
            case "hours":
                Hours = intVal;
                break;
            case "minutes":
                Minutes = intVal;
                break;
            case "seconds":
                Seconds = intVal;
                break;
        }

        return new TimeSpan(Hours, Minutes, Seconds);
    }
}
```

Note that I'll need to use a different converter instance for each timer since I rely on the Hour, Minute, and Second Properties.